# Fried my gpio pins?

Tags: gpio, power, supply

I might have fried my gpio pins. I have a pie 3b with Hyperion installed and I’m trying to use it to run a set of ws2812 led lights. The led lights are running off of a 5v 8amp power supply and the pi is running off of a cell phone charging cable. Anyways I ran a jumper wire from gpio 18 to the data in wire on the led and it lite up but was just producing random colors and the lights would flicker off and on sporadically. After doing a little research I thought that maybe I needed to hook up a common ground between the two so I used a jumper wire between the gnd on the led and pin 6 on the pi and now I can’t get the led to light up at all. Did I toast the gpio pins? I don’t currently have a volt meter but plan on getting one in the next few days. Can I run a test with the volt meter between gpio 18 and one of the ground pins to see if I  shorted it out?

Comment: See https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Testing and report the results.

Comment: Ok I tried to install pigpio by doing sudo apt-get upgrade then sudo apt-get install pigpio. It looks like I’ve got the latest version but when I run the command sudo pigpio or ./gpio test it says command not found. I have like 1 day Linux experience so forgive my ignorance. I would appreciate any time you could give me but your going to have to go slow. I’m still in the 101 class

Comment: The command to start the daemon is `sudo pigpiod`.  The test itself is a shell script which you need to download from the link. Or `wget http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/code/gpiotest.zip` then `unzip gpiotest.zip` then `./gpiotest`

Comment: @joan I also had problem finding `gpiotest`.  It would be a good idea that this procedure is specified somewhere (say, on your webpage).

Answer (score 0):

No one can say. You need to perform some tests.

Whenever you connect any device to the Pi you MUST connect the Gnd **FIRST**. (For the pedants there are a few exceptions where another pin is used as common).

If you connected the Gnd to a live circuit there is the possibility you did other damage.

Most of these LED strips NEED a 5 V logic signal to drive them - usually via a level converter.
The fact that it does not work with a 3.3 V logic signal does not necessarily indicate a problem.

Comment: It was somewhat working before I added the gnd into the mix. When I was only using a jumper wire from gpio 18 to  the data in on the leds they would light up but not the right colors and they would sporadically flash on and off. Even since I added the ground wire I cannot get anything out of the leds even when I remove the ground wire like before.

Comment: So I need to try and add a logic level shifter to up the volts to the leds to 5v?

Comment: P.s thanks for getting back to me so soon. I appreciate the help